# How to fix the Error Code 1062 :Duplicate entry in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating table 'book' to insert book details : book_id(ISBN),title, price,publisher with book_id is set to 'primary key'. When I run the insert commmand I recept the "Duplicate entry" Error like this

**Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' 0.016 sec**

Here is my code:

```
create table book (
book_id integer primary key,
title varchar(40) not null,
price decimal check (price>0),
publisher varchar(30) not null
                  );
insert into book
values (9784295002680,'Basic Informatic Exam',1280,'Impress'),
(9784781912400,'Numeric calculation',1850,'Science'),
(9784800314673,'prepare for SPI',1400,'Yoizumi'),
(9784797371260,'Java programming lesson',2400,'SB Creative'),
(9784797377026,'Understand C',2300,'SB Creative');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `book_id`s you are using are larger than what `int` column can accept.

Surprisingly, they are apparently stored as the max `int` value which is `2147483647`. Thus your 4 inserts are actually having the same key, which explains the error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the system here automatically set 'int' data type to signed which range from -2147483637 to 2147483647